# Delphi 'private' clause (directive) does not work

Tags: delphi, class, object, private

I'm trying to check if my private procedures are really private. But it works the way it shouldn't.

Please help me, maybe I missed something about how the incapsulation should work.

This code should not work. I guess. But it works.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
    tmyclass = class
    private
      procedure one;
    end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure tmyclass.one;
begin
  ShowMessage('1');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var myclass:tmyclass;
begin
  myclass.one;
end;

end.
```

Thank you. (Delphi-7, Win7 x64).

Comment: This is explained clearly in the documentation. Without wishing to be rude, you should read the documentation first, when you come across something you don't understand. Asking a question without doing so comes across as lazy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`private` is for a `unit`.

With more recent version of Delphi, you can use `strict private` to get the expected behavior.

Comment: Are you saying that it was normal system behaviour? No bugs in Delphi, no settings to change? Please, point out, what versions are you referring as 'more recent'?

Comment: Yes, it is normal behavior. Classes that are declared in the same unit are implicit friends of each other, so they can access each other's `protected` and `private` members. `strict protected` and `strict private` were introduced in Delphi 8 to avoid implicit friendship. However, `strict` did not exist yet in Delphi 7.

Comment: With Delphi, yes. `strict private` is used to get a **private** between **classes** in the **same unit**. But it didn't exist with version 7.

Comment: Moreover, you can create a second `unit`, add it in the `uses` of `unit1` and move your `tmyclass` in the second unit...you will see the behavior you were expecting.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of `private` is clearly [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Classes_and_Objects#Visibility_of_Class_Members):

> ### Private, Protected, and Public Members
>
> A **private** member is invisible outside of the unit or program where its
>   class is declared. In other words, a **private** method cannot be called
>   from another module, and a **private** field or property cannot be read or
>   written to from another module. By placing related class declarations
>   in the same module, you can give the classes access to one another's
>   **private** members without making those members more widely accessible.
>   For a member to be visible only inside its class, it needs to be
>   declared **strict private**.
>
> A **protected** member is visible anywhere in the module where its class
>   is declared and from any descendent class, regardless of the module
>   where the descendent class appears. A **protected** method can be called,
>   and a protected field or property read or written to, from the
>   definition of any method belonging to a class that descends from the
>   one where the **protected** member is declared. Members that are intended
>   for use only in the implementation of derived classes are usually
>   **protected**.
>
> A **public** member is visible wherever its class can be referenced.
>
> ### Strict Visibility Specifiers
>
> In addition to **private** and **protected** visibility specifiers, the Delphi
>   compiler supports additional visibility settings with greater access
>   constraints. These settings are **strict private** and **strict protected**
>   visibility. These settings can be used in Win32 applications.
>
> Class members with **strict private** visibility are accessible only
>   within the class in which they are declared. They are not visible to
>   procedures or functions declared within the same unit. Class members
>   with **strict protected** visibility are visible within the class in which
>   they are declared, and within any descendent class, regardless of
>   where it is declared. Furthermore, when instance members (those
>   declared without the **class** or **class var** keywords) are declared **strict
>   private** or **strict protected**, they are inaccessible outside of the
>   instance of a class in which they appear. An instance of a class
>   cannot access **strict protected** or **strict protected** instance members in
>   other instances of the same class.
>
> Delphi's traditional **private** visibility specifier maps to the CLR's
>   assembly visibility. Delphi's **protected** visibility specifier maps to
>   the CLR's assembly or family visibility.
>
> **Note**: The word strict is treated as a directive within the context of a class declaration. Within a class declaration you cannot declare
>   a member named 'strict', but it is acceptable for use outside of a
>   class declaration.

Your version of Delphi, Delphi 7, does not support the `strict` specifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two sample units to show the visibility of `private`, `protected` and `public` parts from a class.

```
unit BaseClass;

interface

type
  TBaseClass0 = class
  strict private
    FStrictPrivate : Integer;
  private
    FPrivate : Integer;
  strict protected
    FStrictProtected : Integer;
  protected
    FProtected : Integer;
  public
    FPublic : Integer;

    procedure DoSomeThing; virtual;
  end;

  TBaseClass1 = class( TBaseClass0 )

  public
    procedure DoSomeThing; override;
  end;

procedure DoSomeThing( ABase : TBaseClass0 );

implementation

{ TBaseClass0 }

procedure TBaseClass0.DoSomeThing;
begin
  FStrictPrivate := 0;
  FPrivate := 0;
  FStrictProtected := 0;
  FProtected := 0;
  FPublic := 0;
end;

{ TBaseClass1 }

procedure TBaseClass1.DoSomeThing;
begin
  inherited;
  // FStrictPrivate := 1; // no access
  FPrivate := 1;
  FStrictProtected := 1;
  FProtected := 1;
  FPublic := 1;
end;

procedure DoSomeThing( ABase : TBaseClass0 );
begin
  with ABase do
    begin
      // FStrictPrivate := 3; // no access
      FPrivate := 3;
      // FStrictProtected := 3; // no access
      FProtected := 3;
      FPublic := 3;
    end;
end;

end.
```

---

```
unit BaseClass2;

interface

uses
  BaseClass;

type
  TBaseClass2 = class( TBaseClass0 )

  public
    procedure DoSomeThing; override;
  end;

procedure DoSomeThing( ABase : TBaseClass0 );

implementation

{ TBaseClass2 }

procedure TBaseClass2.DoSomeThing;
begin
  inherited;
  // FStrictPrivate := 2; // no access
  // FPrivate := 2; // no access
  FStrictProtected := 2;
  FProtected := 2;
  FPublic := 2;
end;

procedure DoSomeThing( ABase : TBaseClass0 );
begin
  with ABase do
    begin
      // FStrictPrivate := 4; // no access
      // FPrivate := 4; // no access
      // FStrictProtected := 4; // no access
      // FProtected := 4; // no access
      FPublic := 4;
    end;
end;

end.
```