# Compiler allows call to protected method in sibling class, but calls base class

Tags: delphi, virtual-functions

To my thinking, the code below should fail to compile because the method `TSubB.DoSomething` is protected, thus not visible from `TSubA.DoSomething`. (They are siblings, not parent/child.) In fact it compiles and when you run it, it actually calls `TBase.DoSomething`. (I got burned by this because I'd forgotten `DoSomething` was protected.)

Now it gets weird. If I paste the code from *uBase.pas* into *Project1.dpr* and remove *uBase.pas* from the project, I do indeed get a compiler error on that line.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

(Sorry to paste so much code. This really does seem to be the minimal test case.)

**Project1.dpr**

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  uBase in 'uBase.pas',
  uSubB in 'uSubB.pas';

var
  obj : TBase;
begin
  obj := TSubA.Create;
  Writeln(obj.Something);
  obj.Free;
end.
```

**uBase.pas**

```
unit uBase;
interface
type
  TBase = class (TObject)
  protected
    class function DoSomething : string; virtual;
  public
    function  Something : string;
  end;

  TSubA = class (TBase)
  protected
    class function DoSomething : string; override;
  end;

implementation
uses
  uSubB;

function TBase.Something : string;
begin
  Result := DoSomething;
end;

class function TBase.DoSomething : string;
begin
  Result := 'TBase'; // Override in subclass.
end;

class function TSubA.DoSomething : string;
begin
  Result := 'Same as ' + TSubB.DoSomething; // Expect compiler error here
end;
end.
```

**uSubB.pas**

```
unit uSubB;

interface

uses
  uBase;

type
  TSubB = class (TBase)
  protected
    class function DoSomething : string; override;
  end;

implementation

class function TSubB.DoSomething : string;
begin
  Result := 'TSubB';
end;

end.
```

---

**Edit**

If you move all the code from uBase.pas into Project1.dpr and remove uBase.pas from the project, then the compiler no longer accepts the call to TSubB.DoSomething. I'm not sure why this is any different in terms of visibility to the compiler.

**Revised Project1.dpr**

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
//  uBase in 'uBase.pas',
  uSubB in 'uSubB.pas';

type
  TBase = class (TObject)
  protected
    class function DoSomething : string; virtual;
  public
    function  Something : string;
  end;

  TSubA = class (TBase)
  protected
    class function DoSomething : string; override;
  end;

function TBase.Something : string;
begin
  Result := DoSomething;
end;

class function TBase.DoSomething : string;
begin
  Result := 'TBase'; // Override in subclass.
end;

class function TSubA.DoSomething : string;
begin
  Result := 'Same as ' + TSubB.DoSomething; // Actual compiler error
end;

var
  obj : TBase;
begin
  obj := TSubA.Create;
  Writeln(obj.Something);
  obj.Free;
end.
```

Comment: About visibility of `private`, `protected` and combined with `strict` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554781/delphi-private-clause-directive-does-not-work/16558763#16558763

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TSubB.DoSomething` is indeed not visible. But the compiler looks in all ancestor classes for `DoSomething`. The first one it finds is `TBase.DoSomething` which is visible. Hence the program compiles.

As to your edit, that changes everything. After your edit you have two different `TBase` classes. The one defined in the dpr file, and the one defined in the `uBase` unit. That's you intend. And there's really no point defining base classes in a dpr file because units cannot use dpr files.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why it should look in ancestor classes when I'm calling on a specific class type (rather than an object instance), though I can accept that "them's just the rules". It's more troubling to me why moving the definitions of TBase and TSubA into Project1.dpr stops the compiler finding the ancestor class. Perhaps there's some major misconception I need to dislodge from my brain...!

Comment: @IanGoldby The compiler always searches through its ancestors. For instance, consider how the `Free` method is found. When you call `Free` on one of your classes, the compiler does not find it in your derived class. It has to search all the way back up to `TObject` to find it. This is just the standard method resolution. When you move `TBase` and `TSubA` into the .dpr file, those classes are only visible in the .dpr file. None of your other units can see them. Units cannot see declarations made in the .dpr file.

Comment: Sorry, I was being closed-minded on the first point. Of course it searches its ancestors; it would do that even if obj was declared as a TSubA (rather than TBase), so the same must be true when calling on a class type. Nothing to do with polymorphism.

Comment: On the second point - getting rid of uBase.pas - I don't see in what way the visibility changes. TSubA.DoSomething can see TBase.DoSomething but not TSubB.DoSomething whether the former two are in uBase.pas or on Project1.dpr. How has the visibility changed?

Comment: If you make the method non-virtual then it gets quite interesting. Your call to `TSubB.DoSomething` can bind to either `TBase.DoSomething` or `TSubB.DoSomething` depending on which unit you make the call from. This one of the strange consequences of Delphi's file based visibility rules.

Comment: Sorry, I modified by previous comment, but I don't think it affects the sense. Thanks for your patience. I think I understand it now.

Comment: As for your other point I no longer know what you are talking about. You described moving class declarations to the dpr file. But I doubt you really did that. It's hard to comment on that which I cannot see. I think I explained how the code in your original question compiles.

Comment: I've appended the modified Project1.dpr file to my question. Sorry I wasn't clearer before.

Comment: Which question do you want us to answer? If we answer this new one, will that be it? The dpr change introduces a new version of the classes. TSubB derives from uBase.TBase. But TSubA derives from the TBase in the dpr file. You now have two TBase classes. Ask yourself how TSubB can derive from a class defined in a dpr file.

Comment: There were two parts, but I'm now focusing on the second part: "Now it gets weird. If I paste the code from uBase.pas into Project1.dpr and remove uBase.pas from the project, I do indeed get a compiler error on that line. Can anyone explain what's going on?" I promise that will be it.

Comment: I've explained it now in the comment above and the answer.

Comment: Doh! I forgot to remove the `uses uBase` from uSubB.pas. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Exactly. The file was still there, and so still picked up.